# Boot splash displaying on wrong screen in dualscreen setup

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, kubuntu, multiple-monitors, plymouth

My setup is the following:

- One monitor connected through DisplayPort (primary) to the NVidia card,
- One monitor connected through VGA to the motherboard, rotated 90 degrees to the right.

Everything is well in everyday usage, there is just one thing that bugs me, the bootsplash appears on the secondary monitor, not rotated accordingly, while the primary screen just displays a cursor.

I'm using Kubuntu 18.04, but it happened before on Xubuntu 18.04, so I think it might be Ubuntu or just Plymouth related issue. Does anybody know if it can be fixed and if so, how to do it?